# DHTMLX Gantt Chart with Reactjs doesn't show scroll

Tags: reactjs, charts, dhtmlx

i'm using react ver 16.7.0 and DHTMLX Gantt ver 7.0.11, Standard Edition. The problem is scroll column is doesn't show in monitor 24" or more but it can show in my laptop monitor (14")

my layout code

```
gantt.config.grid_elastic_columns = true;

    gantt.config.columns=[
        {name:"text",       label:"Task name",      width: '*', min_width: 300, max_width: 1200, tree:true, },
        {name:"assignTo",   label:"Assign To",      align: "center", width: '*', min_width: 100, max_width: 1200, },
        {name:"start_date", label:"Start Date",     align: "center", width: '*', min_width: 100, max_width:200, },
        {name:"endDate",    label:"Date Line",      align: "center", width: '*', min_width: 100, max_width:200, },
        // {name:"duration",   label:"Duration",       align: "center" },
        {name:"budgetHour", label:"Budget Hour",    align: "center" },
    ];

    gantt.config.grid_width = 500;
    
    gantt.config.layout = {
        css: "gantt_container",
        cols: [
            {
            width: 500,
            min_width: 300,
        
            // adding horizontal scrollbar to the grid via the scrollX attribute
            rows:[
                {view: "grid", scrollX: "gridScroll", scrollable: true, scrollY: "scrollVer"}, 
                {view: "scrollbar", id: "gridScroll"}  
            ]
            },
            {resizer: true, width: 1},
            {
                rows:[
                    {view: "timeline", scrollX: "scrollHor", scrollY: "scrollVer"},
                    {view: "scrollbar", id: "scrollHor"}
                ]
            },
            {view: "scrollbar", id: "scrollVer"}
        ],
    };
```

in monitor 14" have scroll
[image]

here in monitor 24"
[image]

*i try in 19" monitor scroll is showed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fix just type

gantt.config.scroll_size = 20;